# What is the exact semantic of reduce in clojure?

Tags: clojure

The Clojure docs regarding `(reduce f val coll)` state:

> If val is supplied, returns the result of applying f to val and the
>   first item in coll, then applying f to that result and the 2nd item,
>   etc.

So I tried:

```
(reduce str ["s1" "s2"] "s3")
```

Which leads to:

```
"[\"s1\" \"s2\"]s3"
```

However, when I try

```
(apply str ["s1" "s2"])
```

I get:

```
"s1s2"
```

So why does the vector get converted into its string representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "picture" view for others who may see this question. Clojure's `reduce` is a left fold. For Haskell programmers `foldl`.

It creates the following structure

```
(reduce - 0 (range 1 3))
(- (- (- 0 1) 2) 3)
```

or infix

```
(((0 - 1) - 2) - 3)
```

The intuition being it's a left fold because the parens drift towards the left

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I misread the docs. So reduce actually does this:

```
(str ["s1" "s2"] "s3")
```

Which evaluates to:

```
"[\"s1\" \"s2\"]s3"
```

Because `str` needs to convert its arguments to string!